# Ignoring invalid input features with Intersection tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, intersection, null-geometry

In QGIS 2.18, when I used the Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Intersection tool, I was able to check an option which said "Ignore NULL geometries [optional]".

Now I've downloaded QGIS 3.2 and that option no longer exists. But when I try to create the intersection between two layers I'm working on, I get a message saying that there is an invalid geometry somewhere and that I should either fix it it or "change the Processing setting to the 'Ignore invalid input features' option."

But that option doesn't exist! Or if it does exist, I just can't find it anywhere.

Does anyone know how/where to change this setting in QGIS 3.2?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Go to Settings > Options > Processing and under General change to Ignore features with invalid geometries.

[image: Processing Settings]

Alternatively, it's also worth checking [the answer by A.Oikonomidis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/297898/9839) as well as other tools available in the processing toolbox to fix invalid geometries in the original dataset.

Comment: As alternative, QGIS may provide preinstalled plugin to fix shapefile (polygon) geometry, which is "fix geometries" plugin.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and tried to solve it by using Geometry Checker plugin. However it takes a lot of time, so if you want a quick solution then you could ignore invalid geometries. For me though, ignoring invalid geometries led to not getting all results so I had to use the "Do not filter(better performance)" choice to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the settings in Qgis 3.0/3.0.2 didn't work for me, but it did with the MMQGIS plugin.

That plugin has been indespendable for me, and way more reliable than what's available with QGIS. And it adds many, many additional features.

Strongly suggest you add the plugin!

Process:

MMQGIS > Modify > Convert Geometry Type > New Geometry > Lines

Comment: User can install MMQGIS Plugin by: Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins > All > MMQGIS