# Matching lower level shapefiles with higher level shapefiles

Tags: qgis, geometry, qgis-processing, filtering

I was trying to combine two shapefiles with different levels of administrative units. when I run it, it is showing error like this.

> Feature (344) from “Sector_Boundary_2006” has invalid geometry. Please fix the geometry or change the “Invalid features filtering” option for this input or globally in Processing settings.
> Execution failed after 1.22 seconds

How can I address this issue?

Comment: It looks like you have features with invalid geometries and you need to fix them, otherwise, you can ignore those invalid features, but the results may not be as you wish.  To ignore invalid features, please refer to [Ignoring invalid input features with Intersection tool in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/289063/63384).

Comment: [Fix geometries](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#fix-geometries) then try again

Comment: The Error message says it clearly: fix geometries or "change the “Invalid features filtering” option for this input".